# Replace code using Regex on Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I have a huge file and need to replace some strings, the problem is that they are dynamic but always follow a pattern:

year[4 digits number]/month[2 digits number]/timestamp[8 digits number]/file[random string ending with extension]

Some examples:

```
2017/07/24204301/a-4.png
2017/07/24204318/a-5-e1501986401369.png
2017/11/24211223/questao10branca-172x300.png
```

I need to remove the timestamp on all occurrences, then the above example would become:

```
2017/07/a-4.png
2017/07/a-5-e1501986401369.png
2017/11/questao10branca-172x300.png
```

How can I achieve this using Regexp and Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you think is a "timestamp" is "day hour minute second", so you want the day removed?

Comment: You can use [`/\d{8}(?=/)`](https://regex101.com/r/z5SS41/1) or [`(?<=^\d{4}/\d{2}/)\d{8}/`](https://regex101.com/r/z5SS41/2)

Comment: As much as I loathe regular expressions, this is one of those times where it is the perfect tool for the job. But you'll never see me admit it in public.

Comment: @MikeHofer aren't these posts public? lol

Comment: @ctwheels I deny everything.

Answer (score 0):

Given the examples you presented, there are a couple of regular expressions that will work for you.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/z5SS41/1)

```
/\d{8}(?=/)
```

- `/` Match this literally
- `\d{8}` Match any digit exactly 8 times
- `(?=/)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a literal `/`

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/z5SS41/2)

```
(?<=^\d{4}/\d{2}/)\d{8}/
```

- `(?<=^\d{4}/\d{2}/)` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is the following:

  - `^` Assert position at the start of the string
  - `\d{4}` Match any digit exactly 4 times
  - `/` Match this literally
  - `\d{2}` Match any digit exactly twice
  - `/` Match this literally
- `\d{8}` Match any digit exactly 8 times
- `/` Match this literally